# How can I use classes from VisualBasic-Express in VBA for Excel or Access projects?

Tags: excel, dll, com-interop, vba

I saved my VB-Express code as .dll and registered it with regasm and made a .tlb file.

But when I try to run a function from it in an Excel-modul I get: **Run-time error ‘453’: Can’t find DLL entry point RegisterServiceProcess in kernel32**

What step did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner’s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/ 
or better still try out ExcelDNA ( http://groups.google.com/group/ExcelDna )

Answer (score 1):

I think you're creating a .Net dll and trying to call it from a COM-oriented environment (VBA), which isn't going to work without help. If I'm guessing right, then you need to investigate the COM Interop elements of .Net: Google throws up lots of promising-looking links, one of which is [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/nettocom.aspx).

It looks a bit unpleasant, but I expect the nastiness can be tucked away somewhere...

Comment: Thanks Mike! Maybe its because I didn't copy it to the Global Assembly Cache that is mentioned in the artikel. Will try that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Microsoft Knowledge Base article: [Can't Run Macro That Calls 16-bit DLL in 32-bit MS Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131525).

Do you have the proper rights to access the DLL?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input to everybody, you helped me a big step further.
After following the guides you provided I got: **Run-time error: '-2147024894' (80070002)': File or assembly name AssemblyName, or one of its dependencies, was not found.**

But I could fix that with this [Workaround](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948461).